# How does one provide a "DLL", "extensions" or "plugins" mechanism for webpack?

Tags: webpack

We run webpack at compile-time, but want to allow for custom extensions at run-time. The location for plugins is known, but not the number or names of plugins. These can only be determined at run-time. Further, these plugins can have their own dependencies. How is this accomplished with webpack?

I'd be fine to leave that corner to use RequireJS, but it looks to me as if the Webpack -> RequireJS migration is an all-or-nothing affair (e.g. because they both define `window.require`).

Background: This works fine with RequireJS: We ship a product for installation on customer hardware (think e.g. Jira, Jenkins or Owncloud). On some installations, the customers write their own dashboard widgets using a documented API. We have a REST call that lists which `/opt/custom/extensions/dashboard/*.js` exist. Each of these can have their own dependencies with e.g.:

```
define([
    'css!./custom-widget-A.css',
], function () {
    // bla bla
}
```

So given that I have `['custom-widget-A.js','custom-widget-B.js']` how would I get these extensions loaded at run-time including their dependencies?

I'd be fine to have to change all the custom extensions, and also fine with requiring the user to run e.g. `/usr/bin/updateCustomExtensions` when adding custom extensions.

I'd like to avoid having node_modules (incl. webpack) on the machine, but we could if that is the only way.

We need to avoid the raw, unminified sources on the machine, only the bundle of our minified sources (for legal reasons - not my decision).

So: How to write `/usr/bin/updateCustomExtensions` and `function loadModules`?

```
// I'm guessing the API needs to be async, since we only know the plugins
// at run-time
function loadDashboardExtensions(callback) {
    // Load them
    getCustomListFromREST(function (modules) {
        loadModules(modules, function () {
            // Caller code that uses extensions
            callback();
        });
    });
}

function loadModules () {
    ????
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can still use RequireJS. RequireJS sets up both `window.require` *and* `window.requirejs`. `window.require` is overwritten by webpack, but `window.requirejs` *is not*.

So `function loadModules` from above can be replaced by `requirejs` as in:

```
function loadDashboardExtensions(callback) {
    // Load them
    getCustomListFromREST(function (modules) {
        requirejs(modules, callback);
    });
}
```

I like it when the answer's code is shorter than the question's.

If one needs to provide the loaded modules with dependencies from the webpack code, one can provide them to the individual modules through their exported/defined functions.